# Error:The Network path not found, when trying to access a LAN computer

Tags: lan, file-sharing

I have two computers connected using adhoc network. When I open **View network computers and devices**, I can see the other computers but when I try to access the computers A Network Error comes showing **Windows can not access \DEB_PC.**
One of my computer is running windows 7 Home Premium and other is Vista starter.File sharing is also on my computer running windows 7 but how to enable file sharing on vista starter edition. 
In the sharing and discovery I only found the Network discovery to turn on but no file sharing  option was there.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Starter is a very limited operating system, which is why it's free.

It does not accept incoming network connections at all, so you cannot share files with it.

From Wikipedia:

> Much like its predecessor, Windows XP Starter Edition, this edition
>   sells in 139 countries such as Russia, Brazil, People's Republic of
>   China, Nepal, Indonesia, Mexico, Pakistan, Philippines, and Thailand.
>   Microsoft does not make it available in developed technology markets
>   such as the United States, Canada, the European Union, Australia, New
>   Zealand, and Japan (although users can install a 30 day trial-version
>   from the 32-bit DVD).[4][5] Vista Starter has significant limitations,
>   such as allowing a **maximum of three applications** with a user interface
>   at once, **not accepting incoming network connections**, a watermark in
>   the corner of the screen, and a physical **memory limit of 1 GB.** Unlike
>   other editions, a 64-bit version of Starter Edition has not been
>   released.[6] It supports AMD's Athlon XP, Duron, Sempron and Geode
>   processors, and Intel's Celeron, Pentium III processors and certain
>   models of Pentium 4. The usable portion of the **hard disk has a limit
>   of 250 GB**. Starter Edition comes with some locale-specific desktop
>   wallpapers not found in other editions of Vista.

If you want a free operating system that is actually full featured, and not extremely limited you are going to have to use a flavour of Linux. I would recommend [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) for someone new, although there are smaller even less computer demanding versions.

Comment: +1 Just to put that final point on it Microsoft says "With Windows Vista Starter, you cannot share your files or folders with others on a network. This means that someone using another computer on that network cannot open or view files that are stored on your computer. You can, however, access another computer's files on a network if file sharing is available on that computer." http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Networking-in-Windows-Vista-Starter

Comment: yes, that is why I can see other computers(windows 7) file on my computer(vista startre) but my computer files are not seen in other computers running windows 7.